# how to apply a different function to each line of input

Tags: c++, io, conditional-statements

I want to apply a different function to each line I read in from a file, but I can't figure out how.

Here's what I've got.

```
 while (input >> val)
 {
    cout << val <<endl;
    input.get();
    input.ignore();
     addfirst(val);
     subsecond(val);
     addAllthird(val);
 }
```

Here's an example input file.

```
3, 5, 6, 7   
4, -4    
999, 777
```

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: store each line to a different... function?

Comment: sorry for the confusing question.. asking for help on SO for first time soo..          - I what to read first line then store in doSth then second line doSth so forth and so on with different function.. thank you so much

Comment: I tried While(getline(inputFile, myfile, ', '), while(inputFIle >> x (x is integer)) I tried pretty much most of the options, but couldn't figure it out.. how to read each line and store in different function..

Comment: I'm editing this to what I think you want the question to be.  As written, it's quite unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is homework.

That said, you could try a switch statement.

```
int countLines=0; 
while(...) {
  cout << val <<endl;

  switch(countLines) {
  case 0:
    input.get(val);
    break;
  case 1:
    input.ignore();
    break;
  case 2:
    addfirst(val);
    break;
  //...
  default:
    std::cerr << "no rule for line " << countLines << ". Trying to process '" << val << "'" << std::endl;
  }

  ++countLines;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is.. I was just thing one way .. getline... Thank you.. This should work.. Thank you thank.. flies

Comment: please upvote and accept if this answer helped :)

Comment: Sorry due.. I am brand new to this.. could you tell me how.. I want to do this Thank you. :)

Comment: I think I did it.. thank you again flies..

Comment: Thanks.  My reputation is currently 1000 precisely :)